# Rails 4 when render nested partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I create todo app using Rails 4,

Use Slim,

TodoList has TodoItem and my views..

```
# show.html.slim
= render @todo_list.todo_items

# _todo_item.html.slim
p
  = todo_item.content
  = link_to "Delete", [@todo_list, todo_item], method: :delete, data: {     confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

actually todo items rendered well, but empty line came out belows
[image: why empty Delete appeared?]

what happen?

I use if method for filter, but I think it is not proper way to remove empty Delete.

additionally informations,
My todolist created by scaffold, todoitem has only create, destroy method.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand this question. Is the issue that you have a todo with no content? How are you preventing that from happening?

Comment: @ptd  I cant prevent this situation. I have just one item in my database 'sadfasd'. but i dont know why just Delete item was shown